# find a substring with character index

Tags: string, perl, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join two substrings in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889754/how-to-join-two-substrings-in-perl)

How could I find a substring of a string array which corresponds to user entered index of character?

For example: If there is a string `$string = 'MFHYRAKCLAMSCTLPHCAKNDHGCTH';`and it get broken into array `@string = ( "MFHYRA","KCLAM", "SCTLP", "HCAKNDHGCTH" ) ;` now if user enters position of `A` as 6 and 10, how could two corresponding substrings be searched and joined?

Comment: 1) Please show what you have tried so far.  2) The question is not clear; what output do you want?  3)  This is incorrect: `@string = {"MFHYRA","KCLAM", "SCTLP", "HCAKNDHGCTH"};`. The braces make a hash reference.  Just use parentheses instead.

Comment: Question seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889754/how-to-join-two-substrings-in-perl

Comment: @mttrb Well they do not seem to be related, they are exactly the same. And by the same user in fact.

Comment: Just to explain why this is hard to understand: what does it mean to "search" the strings?  What are you searching for?  If the user enters 6 and 10 as the position of `A`, then you already know where the `A`s are.  Do you simply want to join the strings that contain the 6th and 10th character?

Comment: @dan1111 : 1) I have tried to find those substrings which corresponds to user entered positions of `A`  take a look at this(I'm taking a different string here) http://codepad.org/KrLaD8cN  but it's not working properly. 2) In the output I want first two substrings corresponding to position of A (say 4 and 8) as joined.

Comment: @user1746090, thanks for your response.  I think January's answer will work for you. In the future, you should put the entire example code of what you have tried directly in your post using code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you ask is this: we have a position in the initial string. The string gets split up in substrings. In which of the substrings is the position?

Assume that

```
@pos = ( 5, 7, 9 ) ;
```

is the list of positions for which you would like to find the substrings.

```
my $n = 0 ; # current position

my %results ;
foreach my $ss ( @substrings ) {

  $n += length( $ss ) ;

  foreach my $p ( @pos ) {
    if( ! $results{$p} and $p < $n ) { $results{$p} = $ss ; }
  }

}

foreach my $p ( @pos ) {
  print "Position $p, substring $results{$p}\n" ;
}
```

Clearly, this code could use some optimalization, for example -- no need to loop over the elements of `@pos` if we already have a substring for them, and we should break the operation after the last element of `@pos` got its substring, but for a few positions entered for the user this doesn't really matter.